# Mostrar dados na tela de acordo com o ID clicado

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou com um pequeno problema aqui talvez fácil de resolver, porém não estou conseguindo. Tenho uma primeira tela (alunos.php) onde terá vários termos de pesquisa, e um deles será por horário de estudo, onde vão me trazer alguns resultados do banco de dados. Até aqui tudo funcionando perfeitamente. Segue o print da tela da pesquisa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código para que esta pesquisa funcione:

```
<?php
                                                    if($startaction == 5){
                                                            if($acao == "search_time") {
                                                                    if(empty($_POST['select_time'])) {
                                                                        echo'<script type="text/javascript">abre_modal( \'#dialog\' );</script>';
                                                                    } else {
                                                                    //pegar nome via post
                                                                    $searched_time = $_POST['select_time'];
                                                                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE Dia_Horario LIKE '%".$searched_time."%' " );
                                                        $check_time = mysql_num_rows($result);
                                                                        if($check_time >= 1){
                                                                             while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                                                $radio = $ln['ID'];
                                                                                $id = $ln['ID'];
                                                                                $full_name = $ln['Nome_completo'];
                                                                                $hora_estudo = $ln['Dia_Horario'];

                                                        ?>

                            <div class="scroll-y">

                                <tr>
                                    <td> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog01" href="#<?php echo $radio; ?>"> Clicar Aqui</a></td>
                                    <a href="">
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $id; ?>
                                        </td>
                                    </a>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='http://www.dpaulatreinamentos.com/system/teste03/views/pages/aluno.php?id_aluno=<?php echo $id; ?>' class='nomecompleto' title='".$full_name."'>
                                            <?php echo $full_name ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $hora_estudo; ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </div>


                            <?php

                                                                } } else {
                                                                    echo'<script type="text/javascript">abre_modal( \'#dialog\' );</script>';

                                                                }
                                                                }
                                                            }

                                                            }

                                ?>
```

Depois que clicamos no nome do aluno, é carregado uma nova pagina, nesta pagina terá os dados completos do aluno porém com campos para edição onde eu poderei trabalhar somente com este aluno, cadastrar novas aulas, mudar dados mas somente deste aluno, já está puxando o ID no link e carregando a nova pagina já com o ID na URL, porém os dados não aparecem, segue print da segunda tela.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue parte do código que eu coloquei:

```
 <?php 



    $searched_time = $_POST['select_time'];

                               $pegaid = $_GET["ID"];
                                                                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE ID = '$pegaid'" );
                                                        $check_time = mysql_num_rows($result);
                                                                        if($check_time >= 1){
                                                                             while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                                                $radio = $ln['ID'];
                                                                                $id = $ln['ID'];
                                                                                $full_name = $ln['Nome_completo'];
                                                                                $hora_estudo = $ln['Dia_Horario'];

       echo $id;                           

  ?>
   <form>
     <?php echo $pegaid; ?>
     <input type="text" class="txt-medium bradius" value="<?php echo $full_name; ?>"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Atualizar" class="sb-search-medium" />
  </form>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Será que teria alguém para me ajudar? Se sim, agradecerei muito.

Answer (score 1):

primeiro aconselho que trabalhe no `mysqli` depois você pode selecionar apenas  tabela que é

```
SELECT * FROM alunos
```

depois você da um

```
<? php while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
```

depois lista cada um que que vai só exibir e ou que vai editar

```
<div id="<?php echo $ln['id']; ?>">

<h4><?php echo $ln['Nome_completo']; ?></h4>
<p><?php echo $ln['Dia_Horario']; ?></p>

</div>
```

e não esqueçe de fecha a while

```
<?php } ?>
```

claro que pra atualizar algumas funções do banco você vai precisar usar o update.

Comment: Não é isso que preciso, mais valeu a ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Não está a funcionar pois no teu print o nome da variavel é (id_aluno), contudo no teu script tu estás a tentar resgatar (ID).

Então não é isso: $pegaid = $_GET["ID"];

E sim isso: $pegaid = $_GET["id_aluno"];

Deve ser esse o motivo, sem aluno não há retorno não é mesmo?